# Editing the DOM using the response from a fetch() call

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, fetch

I am simply trying to edit the DOM using the data I get back from a fetch() request. I am still new to asynchronous programming, and I am sure there is something I am doing wrong here.

Heres the code:

```
window.onload = () => {
  const apiURL = 'https://www.APIurl.......';
  fetch(apiURL).then( (response) => {
    return response.json();
  }).then( (object) => {
    let {values} = object;

    document.getElementById('date1').innerHTML = values[0][0];
    console.log('This will run');
    document.getElementById('date2').innerHTML = values[13][0];
    console.log('This will not run');
    document.getElementById('date3').innerHTML = values[31][0];

  });
}
```

My problem is that I make the call, get the data back just fine, but when I am trying to manipulate the DOM, only the first edit works. I am not sure if the document.getElementById is causing the callback to return early, but I need to edit multiple elements on the DOM with the data I get back.

If there is a better way to do this, or if anyone has a fix, that would be great!

Thanks!!

Comment: Getting elements or modifying them does not cause an early return, although if there's an *error*, it may halt execution. Check your JS console. Beyond that it's difficult to help without at least knowing the DOM structure in question.

Comment: If I understood it correct, if fails on this line `document.getElementById('date2').innerHTML = values[13][0];`, and for us to help with that we need to see both what `values` is and the HTML.

Comment: @DaveNewton @ LGSon  Thank you for the replies. I have spun up a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/limawajubo/edit?html,console,output) so you can all see the full code structure. I apologize for everything being in one file/place. I need it to be in one place as this is a real hacky fix for a code module on a website I am building. Thanks!

Comment: Create a `catch()` block and log you error in the console. My guess is that either `date2` doesn't exist and you're trying to set innerHTML of undefined or `values[13]` is undefined and you're accessing [0] of undefined.

Comment: You're attempting to access elements that do not exist; seems pretty straight-forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting an error `"TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"` which means that you're selecting element, this element doesn't exist in the DOM (`null` is returned) and you're trying to set `innerHTML` property of `null`.

In order to fix this you have to add elements with `date2` and `date3` to your markup so you can set their `innerHTML`.

Also in order to log errors from your Promises add `catch()` block as described in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: You're totally right, I was trying to set values for elements that I did not even create in the DOM yet. Cannot believe that I did not realize that sooner. Thanks for much for all the help everybody!